# Utility that fills folders and subfolders with random files

Tags: java, multithreading, directory, subdirectory

I need to create a multi-threaded utility that, at startup, *fills a specific folder with files in accordance with the following algorithm*:

> For TEST_TIME seconds:
>
> 1. Creates SUBFOLDERS_COUNT sub-folders (average depth = SUBFOLDERS_COUNT/3).
> 2. Populates each folder, including the root one (SUBFOLDERS_COUNT + 1), with JSON files once per PERIOD_TIME seconds with FILES_COUNT
>      files using one thread per folder (no thread pool needed here).

I have a class for generating random JSON files:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import net.andreinc.mockneat.MockNeat;

public class JsonCreator {

    public String createJson() {
        MockNeat mockNeat = MockNeat.threadLocal();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .create();

        String json = mockNeat
                .reflect(Author.class)
                .field("authorName", mockNeat.names().first())
                .field("authorSurname", mockNeat.names().last())
                .map(gson::toJson)
                .val();
        return json;
    }
}
```

But I need to learn **how to implement a multi-threaded utility for creating folders and subfolders**, as described above, in which I can call this json auto-generation method.

Comment: Which part of the task you have problems with? With creating folders/subfolders? Or making it multithreaded?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I know how to create folders using File.mkdir (). I have a problem with make folders and subfolders created according to a given algorithm.